# Open dialogbox or popup or messagebox after entire page loads using javascript or bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have jsp/javascript page which shows some of the content based on some business logic. This page loads some data that being pulled from database. Sometimes Page Load can take more time. So there is no specific time.

Things to do:

Show a popup/messagebox/dialogbox in the middle of screen **after the entire page is loaded**. should have close or "X" button to close.

Popup/messagebox/dialogbox is sequence of 4-5 screens/content messages. Meaning as soon as popup comes it shows 1st content, then there should be "next" or ">" sort of icon within that popup screen. clicking on that it should proceed to next screen or content. When you arrive at last content or screen, you should be able to scroll back to first message.

I have tried using https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp
and https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp.
With that I am having difficulty showing modal or carousel inside messagebox/popup/dialogbox at **the middle of screen after entire page is loaded**

I followed some of the questions here on stackoverflow. They cover all basic things, but not exactly this specific scenario.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve? make a user wait until the page loads? if so why don't you try page loading icon until the page loads completely there is a link to an example on how to achieve that https://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely

Comment: @MakheleSabata No, I am not trying to show page loading icon. I want to show messagebox/popup/dialogbox at middle of screen as soon as page load completes. That scenario is already explained in description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the W3.CSS modal, there's a little hint in their first example on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp). In the `onclick` attribute on the button, there's a little Javascript snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'
```

To get that behavior when the page is finished loading, you can put it into an event listener on the `window` object that waits for the `load` event [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load).

Here's a small example using the boilerplate from the W3.CSS modal page:

```html
<!-- In your HTML -->
<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <span
        onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
        class="w3-button w3-display-topright">
        &times;
      </span>
      <p>Where your carousel goes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
/* 
  In a <script/> tag below the rest of your imported scripts
  or in a separate, linked .js file.
*/

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'block';
});
```

As far as the carousel, you can just replace the `<p />` element inside the modal with the relevant code. I'd start by just copy/pasting the W3Schools slideshow [example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp). Make sure you include the `<link />` and `<script />` required to use Bootstrap and don't forget to replace their images with yours.

If you need any more help, please include some of your code as so folks have better insight into your problem.

Take care!